# How to write paragraph in XML and use Java code?

Tags: java, android, xml

Having trouble writing paragraph in XML and parsing Java variables inside it.

My variable is *Name*(user_input) , expected results on screen is Welcome + "Name".

Tried System.out.println("Hello" + fname); in Java file.
Tried using  in XML file.

XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text= "TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Feedback extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.fnamet);


        TextView fnamef =  findViewById(R.id.first);


        fnamef.setText(text);

        System.out.println("Welcome" + fnamef);

    }
}
```

My fname variable is "John" so we expected the result to be "Hello John" on the device screen, but after entering the name in EditText and click Submit, no message shown.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check that the intent extra is set correctly? If it is not, show the code that starts this `Feedback` activity.

Comment: @Henry         Yes, the code works fine and if the user input their name in the text box and click submit, the name shows be on the screen but the Welcome line does not.

Comment: The "Welcome" will not be shown on the device screen. System out does not go to the device screen in Android. (maybe it is printed to the log). To display something on screen you put it into a view. Furthermore, you have printed the `TextView` object `fnamef` instead of the `text` itself.

Comment: @Henry         After doing research, I have learned that using System out the message is printed on the Logcat, so can we create a `TextView`, and then pass the Logcat content on there to make it shows on the device's screen or do we need another approach method?

Comment: Why do you want to make the detour via `System.out`? Put the string you want to display directly into the `TextView`.

Comment: I though if I worked with java I should use `System.out`, it was my bad for being such a short mind. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it would be better if you provide the code in which you start the `Feedback` activity.

Coming to the answer,

`fnamef.setText(text);`

This only sets the name into the `TextView`.

If value of text is "John" the it shows only John in the `TextView`.

If you want to set text "Welcome John", you might do the following:-

`fnamef.setText("Welcome " + text);`

If you no message is showing then we would like to see the code where you start `Feedback` activity.

Comment: It worked! I did not know it is possible to have a `string` inside `setText()`, I thought inside `setText()` must always be an object. Thank you so much~